# Python: convert space (and other special chars like . , ) to their corresponding unicode representations

Tags: python, string, unicode

I am trying to convert an Arabic phrase into its corresponding unicode representation string and it works fine for the Arabic text.

```
>>> a = ' مساء الخير'
>>> a.strip().decode('utf-8').encode('unicode-escape')
'\\u0645\\u0633\\u0627\\u0621 \\u0627\\u0644\\u062e\\u064a\\u0631'
```

However, I also want the space-character to be converted to its unicode representation ('\u0020'). I am observing similar behaviour with other characters like '.', ',', etc. I finally want to obtain the unicode values of each of the characters in my string as a list *(simply splitting the current string with the delimiter '\u' gives me the incorrect split as the space character becomes combined with the previous unicode representation)*

```
>>> a.strip().decode('utf-8').encode('unicode-escape').split('\\u') 
['', '0645', '0633', '0627', '0621 ', '0627', '0644', '062e', '064a', '0631']
```

eg. I want [ ... '0621', '0020' ...] instead of the current [ ... '0621 ' ...]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It it fine to strip the first space in you do not need it, but if you want to keep the other, it would be simpler to build a list of unicode characters from the string and individually process the characters:

```
[ '%04x' % (ord(i),) for i in a.strip().decode('utf8') ]
```

or if you prefere to use `format` (which is now better)

```
[ '{0:04x}'.format(ord(i)) for i in a.strip().decode('utf8') ]
```

Both yield as expected:

```
['0645', '0633', '0627', '0621', '0020', '0627', '0644', '062e', '064a', '0631']
```

Answer (score 1):

Any particular reason you don't create (scan/read) the string as a unicode string in the first place?

```
In [14]: a = u' مساء الخير'

In [15]: [hex(ord(i)) for i in a]
Out[15]: 
['0x20',
'0x645',
'0x633',
'0x627',
'0x621',
'0x20',
'0x627',
'0x644',
'0x62e',
'0x64a',
'0x631']
```

Comment: I am new to python string encoding. Didn't know one can traverse the python string in this fashion. This solution works fine too! Thanks :)